# Choice of statistical analysis for correlational study

Tags: methodology, statistics, correlation

Good morning,
I am writing a dissertation for my master's degree in psychology. I have to do statistical studies on data that I have collected.
I want to proceed with a correlational analysis.

Hypothesis: The higher the children's autistic trait score, the greater the correlation between perceived predilection interests and perceived cognitive strengths.

I compare the results of a high autistic trait group to a low autistic trait group.
I have 9 normal numeric variables and 8 ordinal and therefore non-normal variables. (13 participants)

for the moment I used a spearman correlation but I have a doubt on the choice of my statistical analysis to use because of my ordinal and non-normal variables.

Can I use the spearman method ? if not, what can I use?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome. What are these variables? Likert scaled ratings? Can you give examples of the data?

Comment: Yes, the ordinal variable (8 variables) data were obtained using a 5-point Likert scale. They are part of a questionnaire on perceived strengths. Do I have to transfer the data for it to be normal? And if so, how?

Comment: @lau are the 8 variables you used items from the same scale? i.e. you can derive a sum score for all 8 responses? also, spearman's correlation is non-parametric, meaning there is no assumption of normality. your data can also be ordinal. if you explain a little more about what data you have, it will be easier to help you. i suspect that your small sample size may be an issue.